# Creating a generic function for an object that can be called with specified inputs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to create a series of objects in JSON like this:

```
const objects = {
  type1: {
    inputs: [value1, resultOfFunction(), value3],
    typeFunction: (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
      //this does a thing with the inputs and returns an output
    }
  },
  type2: {
    inputs: [val1, val2],
    typeFunction: (arg1, arg2) => {
      //this does a thing with these inputs and returns an output
    }
  }
}
```

The point here is that each `type` contains some kind of blackbox function that takes a series of arguments and returns a value. The number of arguments will differ with each type, as will the values of those arguments. I have suggested there is an array `inputs` that specifies what values are to be passed into each function, but I am open to alternatives.

How can I then generically call these functions with their respective inputs? e.g.

```
type1.typeFunction() //obvs this doesn't work
```

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I then generically call these functions with their respective inputs?

You either specify the inputs, perhaps using spread notation:

```
type1.typeFunction(...type1.inputs);
```

...or you define a function on the `type` that does that.

---

Note: In

```
inputs: [value1, resultOfFunction(), value3]
```

`resultOfFunction` will be called as of when that overall object initializer is processed, not later when `type1.typeFunction` is called. Maybe that's what you want, but I thought it was useful to call it out specifically. If it *isn't* what you want, then you have to put that in a function so it's not done until/unless that function is called.